# Does GTA IV multiplayer still work?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I have had gta 4 for quite a long time now and so has my friend. Before he couldn't run it and now he can because he has a new PC. So I wondered if the multiplayer in this game still works. I heard things about Games For Windows Live going down. Will I need a mod for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can play multiplayer**

You don't need mods too.

Games for Windows Live didn't go down. They just stopped accepting new games to it, but you can still play multiplayer on the older games it supports. You can just play multiplayer, as if you would on the day GTA IV was released.

Comment: Sidenote: You can go online with mods if you want (it is fun to mess around, especially with friends, as you can spawn cars etc. too), but you will only be able to play with fellow modders and will not be able to access ranked mode.